# Puppet hiera variable in erb `if` statement

Tags: puppet, erb, hiera

I have a hiera variable in my erb template for one condition check.

```
<% if @server_name == 'jira-dev-api'
```

After upgrading to puppet 5, this variable in the `if` loop does not work. But this will take correct values without the `if` statement in an erb template.

1. I tried puppet lookup for hiera debugging, and it works fine. The variable is defined within the same module as below.

   ```
   module_name::install_confluence_apache_config::server_name=xyz
   ```
2. When I appended a scope with the absolute path like below,

   ```
   scope['module_name::install_confluence_apache_config::server_name']
   ```

   it works.

Is there any change with erb scoping in `if` statement in puppet 5? I was using puppet 3 open source.

Adding more info.

a)server_name is a variable defined in "nodes/%{::clientcert}" yaml file.
b)I was using puppet 3.8 and the working erb template was as below

```
<% if @server_name == 'jira-dev-api'
```

c)upgraded to puppet 5.5.But observed that when i reference server_name variable in erb in a if statement as above the value is not getting.But working when i use

```
scope['module_name::install_confluence_apache_config::server_name']
```

Also this issue is only inside if statment in erb template.

Comment: There is not enough information here to diagnose the problem, nor even enough for me to be confident that I know what you mean by the unusual term "hiera variable".  Please present a [mcve].

Comment: Also in what version of Puppet did your code work as expected?  There *have* been changes to how variable scoping works in ERB templates, but not recently.

Comment: It worked in puppet 3.x.

Comment: If it genuinely is a scope issue and the code worked somewhere in the Puppet 3 frame, then "3.x" is probably not accurate.  My guess would be that the template relies on the variable being obtained from *dynamic scope*, but removal of almost all forms of dynamic scoping was one of the changes between Puppet 2 and Puppet 3.  Early releases of Puppet 3 were a bit buggy, however, in that dynamic scope (erroneously) still worked in templates.  That was fixed in later releases of Puppet 3.

Comment: @JohnBollinger.Thanks added more info in my question.

Comment: Templates access data from Hiera only via lookup functions.  The `@server_name` syntax *strongly* suggests that your template expects to  get the data not from Hiera but from a variable of some class (which perhaps got it from Hiera).  The details are relevant to the question, so again, please present a MCVE.  If you're uncertain what that means or how to create one, then follow the hyperlink in my first comment.

Comment: @SarathS, I also can't understand this question. At a minimum we would need to see the Puppet code that calls the ERB template function. Ideally a minimal, complete, verifiable example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks John and alex.

It was a scope issue as John said it was working before in 3.8 using @syntax may be due to the bug.